# shorthand for and/or in python if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison, shortcut

Is there a shorthand way to write a comparison in an if statement if you are making the same comparison for multiple values. Just curious if anything like this is possible. Thanks for the help!

```
a =1
b =1
c =1

if a == 1 and b ==1 and c == 1:
    print('yes')

# It would be nice if you could do this or something like it.
if a,b,c == 1:
    print('this would be easier')
```

Comment: Is this fine `(a,b,c)==(1,1,2)`??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `all` for `and`:

```
# same as:
# if a == 1 and b == 1 and c == 1:
if all(x == 1 for x in (a, b, c)):
    ...
```

or you can use operator chaining:

```
if a == b == c == 1:
    ...
```

But I don't see this very much in real code.

---

For `or`, you can use `any`:

```
# same as:
# if a == 1 or b == 1 or c == 1:
if any(x == 1 for x in (a, b, c)):
    ...
```

As far as I can remember, there is no operator chaining trick to this one though you *could* use `in`:

```
if 1 in (a, b, c):
    ...
```

This does have some performance implications (i.e. it makes a new tuple just for the comparisons).  Normally this is pretty cheap and wouldn't be noticable in anything but the tightest of loops though.

Comment: Will evaluate the whole list but will work: `all([a == 1, b == 1, c == 1])`.

Comment: `1 in (a, b, c)` might be slower when `a`, `b` and `c` are expensive expressions and `a` already isn't `1` so `b` and `c` wouldn't have to get evaluated. For the same reason, I prefer using `1 == a == b == c` for the `and` case, i.e., putting the "target" first.

Comment: @StefanPochmann -- Yes, the lack of short-circuiting is a big deal if there are lots of elements in the tuple (which is unlikely if you are building it from scratch) or if `a`, `b` and `c` are arbitrary (expensive) expressions rather than simple name lookups ... Based on the phrasing of the question, it looks like OP is doing simple name lookups, but your point should be recognized for other cases...

Answer (score 1):

Something like if the values are hashable:

```
if set((a, b, c)) == {1}:
    # All are 1.
```

Or may be if all of the 3 values are non-negative integers, multiply all of them and see if the result is 1?

```
if a * b * c == 1:
    # All are 1.
```

The generic answer is `all(..)`  as in mgilson's answer.

Comment: You need to be careful with the multiplication one... It's clever, but it doesn't always work.  Consider `a, b, c = 1, -1, -1`  :-)

Comment: Ohh, I should have said non-negative numbers. Let me edit it the answer.

Comment: Why not use `{a, b, c}`? I know you know it, you're using it in `{1}`...

Comment: Multiplication and (especially) building a set are expensive compared to simply chaining a few comparisons.